# Dell Inspiron 1545 dies on boot when on battery

Tags: boot, 20.04, gnome, crash

My Inspiron dies if I try and boot it in battery mode. It is fine if connected to the mains.
I believe this is the relevant part of syslog is below but would be happy to e-mail the full file.:-

```
Jun 18 12:11:49 laptop gnome-shell[1392]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
```

Comment: Is the battery good?  Can you try another one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I unplug the mains after its booted the system continues to run. I don't have another battery to try.  I am inclined to think it's time to replace the whole system

Comment: The required electrical power at boot time may exceed the capacity of your battery,